# NSLayoutAttribute topMargin and bottomMargin (Constraints To Margin) not working in iOS programmatic layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am developing iOS app with swift 4.0 by programmatic constraints. But when running on iOS simulator, mainView.topMargin getting same as mainView.top. I am expecting 20 pixels difference between mainView.topMargin and mainView.top. If anyone having any idea then please help.

I have posted my code below. Please check.

```
    // my scroll view
private let svLogin: UIScrollView = {
    let scroll = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
    scroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow//(hex: Colors.PRIMARY_DARK, alpha: 0)
    scroll.delaysContentTouches = false
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scroll.isScrollEnabled = true
    scroll.isPagingEnabled = false
    scroll.bounces = false
    scroll.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scroll.clipsToBounds = true
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scroll
}()

// This is how I am applying constraints
view.layout(svLogin, .leading, .equal, view, .leading)
view.layout(svLogin, .top, .equal, view, .topMargin)
view.layout(svLogin, .width, .equal, view, .width)
view.layout(svLogin, .bottom, .equal, view, .bottomMargin)

// extension to create programmatic constraints

extension UIView {

@discardableResult
func layout(
    _ leftItem: Any,
    _ leftAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute,
    _ relation: NSLayoutRelation,
    _ rightItem: Any,
    _ rightAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute,
    _ multiplier: CGFloat,
    _ constant: CGFloat
    ) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    if let leftView = leftItem as? UIView {
        leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:       leftItem,
        attribute:  leftAttribute,
        relatedBy:  relation,
        toItem:     rightItem,
        attribute:  rightAttribute,
        multiplier: multiplier,
        constant:   constant
    )
    self.addConstraint(constraint)
    return constraint
}

@discardableResult
func layout(
    _ leftItem: Any,
    _ leftAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute,
    _ relation: NSLayoutRelation,
    _ rightItem: Any,
    _ rightAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute
    ) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    if let leftView = leftItem as? UIView {
        leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:       leftItem,
        attribute:  leftAttribute,
        relatedBy:  relation,
        toItem:     rightItem,
        attribute:  rightAttribute,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant:   0
    )
    self.addConstraint(constraint)
    return constraint
}

@discardableResult
func layout(
    _ leftItem: Any,
    _ leftAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute,
    _ relation: NSLayoutRelation,
    _ constant: CGFloat
    ) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    if let leftView = leftItem as? UIView {
        leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:       leftItem,
        attribute:  leftAttribute,
        relatedBy:  relation,
        toItem:     nil,
        attribute:  .notAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant:   constant
    )
    self.addConstraint(constraint)
    return constraint
}
}
```

Comment: You never tell the layout system that you want a margin of 20px; all your layout constants are 0. In terms of your layout helper methods I think you should write: `view.layout(svLogin, .top, .equal, view, .topMargin, 1, 20)`

Comment: @dr_barto - Same thing will work when work same code with iOS 11.0. When running on iOS 8 and iOS 9 simulator, I am getting this issue only. Also one thing, what you have said is not applicable for iPhone X. because iPhone X having topMargin of 44 px.

Comment: Ah, you get the 20px because of using the topMargin anchor, I see... sorry for missing that. In that case I can only tell you that the _new_  layout system with layout anchors (available since iOS9, I think) makes it pretty easy to layout with iPhone X, there you'd write `view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)` to escape the notch... plus it's rather concise (for an Apple API anyway), so no need for custom layout DSL anymore. But if you need to support iOS 8 that you'd have to provide both old and new layout code.

Comment: @dr_barto - Thanks for replying. Yes you are right.  For supporting iOS 8 I have wrote: *view.layout(svLogin, .top, .equal, topLayoutGuide, .bottom)* by this way. You can check my complete answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by writing separate logic for iOS 11+, iOS 9+, iOS 8+

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            svUploadWorks.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            svUploadWorks.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            svUploadWorks.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            svUploadWorks.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                svUploadWorks.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                svUploadWorks.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                svUploadWorks.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
                svUploadWorks.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            } else {
                view.layout(svUploadWorks, .leading, .equal, view, .leading)
                view.layout(svUploadWorks, .top, .equal, topLayoutGuide, .bottom)
                view.layout(svUploadWorks, .width, .equal, view, .width)
                view.layout(svUploadWorks, .bottom, .equal, bottomLayoutGuide, .top)
            }
        }
```